# upload the picture from gallery or camera by alertdialogue

Tags: android

this is my program, I think it is no problem about the alertdialogue.
But after I select the photo in my gallery, the picture isn't changed.
It is still the original photo that I set in the ImageView.
Could someboby help me know where the problem is?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
ImageView img_logo;<br>
protected static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 0;
protected static final int GALLERY_PICTURE = 1;
private Intent pictureActionIntent = null;
Bitmap bitmap;

Uri selectedImageUri;
String  selectedPath;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    img_logo= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.homepic);
    img_logo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startDialog();
        }

    });
}
 private void startDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    myAlertDialog.setTitle("Upload Pictures Option");
    myAlertDialog.setMessage("How do you want to set your picture?");

    myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Gallery",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    pictureActionIntent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
                    pictureActionIntent.setType("image/*");
                    pictureActionIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                    startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent,
                            GALLERY_PICTURE);
                }
            });

    myAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("Camera",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    pictureActionIntent = new Intent(
                            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent,
                            CAMERA_REQUEST);

                }
            });
    myAlertDialog.show();
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {



    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
     if(data.getData() != null){
       selectedImageUri = data.getData();
     }else{
      Log.d("selectedPath1 : ","Came here its null !");
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "failed to get Image!", 500).show();
     }

     if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
            selectedPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            img_logo.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            Log.d("selectedPath1 : " ,selectedPath);

        } 

        if (requestCode == 10)

        {

           selectedPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
           img_logo.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
           Log.d("selectedPath1 : " ,selectedPath);

        }

    }
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hiiiii", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();

}
public String getPath(Uri uri) {

    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    return cursor.getString(column_index);

} 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView img_logo;
    protected static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 0;
    protected static final int GALLERY_PICTURE = 1;

    private String imgPath;
    private String selectedPath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        img_logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.homepic);
        img_logo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startDialog();
            }

        });
    }

    private void startDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        myAlertDialog.setTitle("Upload Pictures Option");
        myAlertDialog.setMessage("How do you want to set your picture?");

        myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Gallery",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), GALLERY_PICTURE);
                    }
                }
        );

        myAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("Camera",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
                        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

                    }
                }
        );
        myAlertDialog.show();
    }

    public Uri setImageUri() {
        // Store image in dcim
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/", "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".jpg");
        Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        return imgUri;
    }

    public String getImagePath() {
        return imgPath;
    }

    public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            String id = uri.getLastPathSegment().split(":")[1];
            final String[] imageColumns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            final String imageOrderBy = null;
            Uri tempUri = getUri();
            Cursor imageCursor = managedQuery(tempUri, imageColumns,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=" + id, null, imageOrderBy);

            if (imageCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            } else
                return null;
        }

    }

    private Uri getUri() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (!state.equalsIgnoreCase(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            return MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        return MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
                img_logo.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getImagePath()));
                selectedPath = getImagePath();
            } else if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICTURE) {
                img_logo.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getAbsolutePath(data.getData())));
                selectedPath = getAbsolutePath(data.getData());
            }
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hiiiii", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }

    }

}

Add this  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> in AndroidManifest.xml
```

Comment: thank you for your help!
It works now!
But when I choose some pictures,the application program would be stopped.
How could I solve this problem?
And I want to ask one more question....

Comment: Can you please explain more for some pictures ?

Comment: Actually,I don't know why it would happen.
It can work when I choose some pictures,but it can't work when I choose some others.
I think maybe it is because of the storage,but I'm not sure.

Comment: I think it may be some images problem can you please try to with some new images download from net and check is it same problem with those images too or not ?

Comment: I found that I can upload the image which I choose in "Recent" ,but it can't work if I want to upload the image which choosed in "Gallery" or "Photos" or "Dropbox".

Comment: okay so can you please debug the path of selected image from Gallery or Photos or Dropbox and let me know have you getting exact path or not ?

Comment: After I debugged the path,it said the source is not found.